# To convert PHP's while loop to a for -loop

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

**How can you convert the following while loop to a for -loop in PHP?**

```
while( $row2 = pg_fetch_row( $result_tags )
```

While -loops are a source of errors for me.
I see the while -loop as follows.

```
for ( $i = 0 ; $i < count(pg_fetch_row( $result_tags )) ; $i++ )
```

Comment: The error isn't a missing ) in your while statement, is it?

Comment: What sort of problems are you having with the while loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't convert that `while` to a `for`.

`for` loops are used for incremental loops. `while` loops are used to execute code until a condition is `false`. While most `for` loops can be easily converted to `while` loops (`for` loops are just a syntactical enhancements of `while` loops), the opposite is not always possible.

Consider the following loop:

```
while($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) { }
```

This loop will execute until `pg_fetch_row()` returns a [falsy value](http://php.net/empty).

> **Note:** The proper syntax for such a loop would be:
>
> `while(($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) !== FALSE) { }`

Unfortunately, the closest you can come to using a `for` loop is the following:

```
for(; $row = pg_fetch_row($result) ;) {}
```

Which will behave exactly the same as the `while` loop anyway.

> **Note:** Again, the proper syntax for such a loop would be:
>
> `for(; ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) !== FALSE ;) { }`

I think you should go back in your code and find exactly the cause of your problem instead of blaming the use of the `while` loop.

`pg_fetch_row()` returns an array of columns, so you cannot use `count()` on it.

The closest you can come to using a `for` loop would be using `pg_num_rows` as such:

```
for($i = 0; $i < pg_num_rows($result); $i++) {
    $row = pg_fetch_row($result);
}
```

But personally I find that unnecessarily verbose and open to more problems.

Comment: +1. This answer could use an explanation for the "!== FALSE" test, namely that an empty array will be type juggled to a FALSE and the loop will exit, even though `pg_fetch_row(...)` returned a row. Of course, if the rows have no columns, you might want to skip the loop. Also, the "!== FALSE" test is a matter of semantics, not syntax.

Comment: Yes... but you can't say "the proper semantics"... That's why I said syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Going in the other direction, a for loop:

```
for (init; test; incr) {body;}
```

is equivalent to:

```
init;
while (test) {
    body;
    incr;
}
```

That is, a for loop is a special kind of while loop. Personally, I don't see how converting the while loop you give to a for loop will reduce errors.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do this? The better way is to declare/instantiate `$i = 0` and then increment it at the end of the `while` loop.